# Azure Key Vault error message "AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I have Key Vault on Azure and I added Access policies for App registrations with Secret permissions (Get, List, Set, Delete, Recover, Backup, Restore)
I wrote Java code:

```
    String keyVaultUri = "https://myKeyVault.azure.net";

    ClientSecretCredential paramClientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId("MyApplicationId")
            .clientSecret("MyApplicationSecretKey")
            .tenantId("MyTenantId")
            .build();

     SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl(keyVaultUri)
        .credential(paramClientSecretCredential)
        .httpLogOptions(new HttpLogOptions().setLogLevel(HttpLogDetailLevel.BODY_AND_HEADERS))
        .buildClient();

     KeyVaultSecret storedSecret = secretClient.getSecret("mySecret");

     System.out.println("Secret value: "+storedSecret.getValue());
```

I'm using these Maven dependencies:

1. azure-security-keyvault-secretss (version 4.6.2)
2. azure-core (version 1.39.0)
3. azure-identity (version 1.9.0-beta.1)

After I started my code I got this error message Status code 401, "{"error":{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"AKV10000: Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."}}"

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes with your code and I got the **secrete** of my **key vault** at output.

**Code:**

```java
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.models.KeyVaultSecret;

public class KeyVaultKam {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String keyVaultUri = "https://<keyvault-name>.vault.azure.net/";
        String secretName = "<secrete-name>";

        ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId("<client-ID>")
                .clientSecret("<client-secrete>")
                .tenantId("<tenant-ID>")
                .build();

        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(keyVaultUri)
                .credential(credential)
                .buildClient();

        try {
            KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret(secretName);
            System.out.println("Secret value: " + secret.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error retrieving secret: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

I added below **dependencies** to the **pom.xml** file,

```xml
<dependencies>
     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
</dependencies>
```

I created **access policy** for the **client application** as below,

[image]

**Output:**

It **runs successfully** and got the output of my **secrete** as below,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DasariKamali . I did all that you explained in the pictures from your reply but I got the same error message as before. Did you enable something on Azure for your client application?

Comment: @dzivi No, I just created an access policy for the client-ID application. Follow the below steps to create an access policy for the app registration client-ID application.

Comment: @dzivi Step-1: Click on Create access policy like [this](https://i.imgur.com/wSdWDEV.png).
Step-2: Select all like this-[1](https://i.imgur.com/L99Sewm.png), [2](https://i.imgur.com/YAUwaPq.png), [3](https://i.imgur.com/BRGtb76.png) click on next.
Step-3: Enter your app registration client ID [here](https://i.imgur.com/4j8SysX.png) and click on next.
Step-4: Check [this](https://i.imgur.com/0H2h9mF.png) and click on create will create an access policy for the app registration client ID.
Step-5: It will create an access policy for the client like [this](https://i.imgur.com/q04OH2s.png).

Comment: @dzivi Did you get the answer? Are you able to see the key vault secrete output?

Comment: I set everything as you describe for my existing app and key vault on Azure. I'll try to create a new client app and new key vault and try to set everything step by step as you describe.

Comment: I found an issue in my Maven dependencies. I had two different versions of `azure-storage-blob` and that caused this error message. After I deleted one version the code starts working as it should. 
Your answer with an explanation step by step is perfect, so I'll accept your answer.